# Laravel foreach in sub foreach blade

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-5

this is my table:
`t_hasil_temp
|---|-------|----------|-------| 
|id | id_wi | hasil    | nilai |
|---|-------|----------|-------|
|1  | 3     | 45       | 0,53  |
|2  | 3     | 20,45,23 | 0,53  |
|3  | 4     | 21,22    | 0,87  |
|4  | 5     | 45,23    | 0,23  |`

`t_objek 
|---|-------|----|
|id | name  | ...|
|---|-------|----|
|20 | name1 | ...|
|21 | name2 | ...|
|23 | name3 | ...|
|45 | name4 | ...|`

`t_hasil_temp.hasil => t_objek.id`

I want to make looping `t_objek` from `t_hasil_temp.hasil` with the same `id_wi`

example `id_wi => 3`

will show in blade view:
`nilai => 0,53`

first foreach:
`name4`

second foreach:
`name1` and `name4` and `name3`

I'm try like this. But I get just the first `id` from `t_hasil_temp.hasil`

my controller

```
$temps = DB::table('t_hasil_temp')
  ->where('id_wi', $idwisa)
  ->get();

  foreach ($temps as $value) {
    $stemp = DB::table('t_hasil_temp')
    ->where('id', $value->id)
    ->first();

    $temp = explode(",",$stemp->hasil);

    $tempStr = implode(',', $temp);

    $robjeks = DB::table('objek')->whereIn('id', $temp)->orderByRaw(DB::raw("field(id, $tempStr)"))->get();
  }
```

my view

```
@foreach($temps as $tem)
    <ul id="list">
      @foreach($robjeks as $robjek)
        @if(in_array($robjek->id,explode(',', $tem->hasil))) 
          <li class="list_item {{$robjek->kategori}}">
            .....
          </li>
        @endif
      @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

I think there is something wrong with my code, but I don't know. I was resignedly. 
Help me please!

Thanks for attention.

Comment: You are overwriting `$temp = explode(",", $temp->hasil);` (here you have a typo mistake too). But now `$temp` have an array exploded with comma. Not the db record which  you are trying to get in template by `$tem->id`. So change variable name.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know which one should I change?

Comment: can you dd($tem) in your loop first line of blade template

Comment: I got `{#318 ▼
  +"id": 484
  +"id_wi": "484"
  +"hasil": "26,34"
  +"nilai": "0.45416566848485"
}`

Comment: OK good. Now In 2nd foreach also check with the `$robjek` is it also an object and you can access the ID ... because if id do not match then it will not print anything.

Comment: in `dd($robjek)` I get  `{#331 ▼
  +"id": 20
  +"nama_objek": "Penglipuran Village"
  +"kategori": 2}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134737/discussion-between-mading-ne-and-naveed-ramzan).

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the variable values of `$robjeks` you take that each result in the array.

You may try like

```
$temps = DB::table('t_hasil_temp')
  ->where('id_wi', $idwisa)
  ->get();

  foreach ($temps as $value) {
    $stemp = DB::table('t_hasil_temp')
    ->where('id', $value->id)
    ->first();

    $temp = explode(",",$stemp->hasil);

    $tempStr = implode(',', $temp);

    $robjeks[] = DB::table('objek')->whereIn('id', $temp)->orderByRaw(DB::raw("field(id, $tempStr)"))->get();
  }
```

You view should like

```
@foreach($temps as $tem)
    <ul id="list">
      @foreach($robjeks as $robjek)
        @if($tem->id == $robjek->id)
          <li class="list_item {{$robjek->kategori}}">
            .....
          </li>
        @endif
      @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```